# Select where datetime start greater than and end less than

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, date-range

I have a table with start and end field with values such as:

```
start               | end
2021-09-24 17:00:00 | 2021-10-01 08:00:00
```

I have gone foggy headed and can't figure out why this statement results in nothing:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `oncall`
WHERE `start` >= '2021-10-01 02:00:00'
AND   `end`   <= '2021-10-01 08:00:00'
```

although the date range in my example row contains the above range.

I am trying to find any row that overlaps the start and end of the values in the database.

Comment: What is the data type of the `start` and `end` columns.

Comment: Those `DATE_FORMAT()` are doing nothing a bit like `A = A`

Comment: Both columns are DATETIME

Comment: I know the FORMATE is doingg nothing, grasping at straws

Comment: I would go for `WHERE \`start\` >= '2021-10-01 02:00:00' AND \`end\` <= '2021-10-01 08:00:00'`

Comment: But I would also check that there are some rows that actually meet that criteria

Comment: The dates I supplied in the post are taken straight from the DB, I have just run it again without the DATE_FORMAT() and still no result.

Comment: Ok so there is something else going on here. Can you cretae a DBFiddle so we can all see this failing

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i5HNXWUkDy4hqJZpn4Ubmp/0

Comment: Did you try:  CAST('2021-09-30 02:00:00' as DateTime) ?

Comment: Try setting a Date in the row that actually fits between the search criteria https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i5HNXWUkDy4hqJZpn4Ubmp/1

Comment: But if you try to search BETWEEN '2021-10-01 02:00:00' AND '2021-10-01 08:00:00' you get nothing.  That falls into the time frame.

Comment: @riggs look closely. The condition in the query `start >= 2021-10-01 02:00:00` will not match the row with start = `2021-09-24 17:00:00`.

Comment: @SalmanA `2021-09-24` is neither `>` nor `=` to `2021-09-30` or am I now officially loosing my marbles

Comment: Maybe you should tell us why you think that row should be selected and then we can build a query that matches your requirement

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am trying to write a query that will match any rows whos start is >= to START and <= to END.  This is updated and still doesn't work - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i5HNXWUkDy4hqJZpn4Ubmp/3

Comment: It is working perfectly. The rows in the table DONT match that criteria. I am beginning to doubt my own sanity, so can someone please help out here @Gordonlonoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the entry in your database and the query you're using, it seems like you're actually looking for a date interval ***overlap*** query i.e. a query that checks if `[2021-10-01 02:00:00, 2021-10-01 08:00:00)` overlaps `[2021-09-24 17:00:00, 2021-10-01 08:00:00)` somehow.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `oncall`
WHERE @d2 > `start` AND `end` > @d1

-- replace @d1 and @d2 with actual values
```

Note that this query works for all kinds of overlap. For example if you have this pair of dates in your database:

```
2021-10-11 | 2021-10-15
```

then all of these input pairs will match:

```
2021-10-01 | 2021-10-12
2021-10-14 | 2021-10-20
2021-10-01 | 2021-10-20
2021-10-11 | 2021-10-14
```

Comment: Thank you for this, just couldn't see it.

Comment: Maybe you could update the question so that it gives a Vague Idea that this is actually what you wanted to achieve